# How to custom the iPad Icon home screen for an application?

Tags: ipad, icons

I put in my project a png file for the icon. I respect the dimensions (72x72) and my icon does not appear in my home screen. I still have the white icon by default...
It is named icon.png , the name is right ?
The weird thing is the icon appear on my simulator but not in my device

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name it whatever you want; but you need to set the icon in your plist file. The CFBundleIconFile key ("Icon File"). Set that equal to the name of your image. If your icon shows up on your simulator, but not your device, make sure you do a clean build.

Comment: I add the name in my info.plist from my project. Do I put the name of the image with the extention or not ?
What you mean by "do a clean build"?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Use the full name, including extension. By a clean build, I mean delete the existing application from your device, chose "clean" from the Xcode build menu, and then choose "run" to reinstall the application. Sometimes this fixes issues related to old resources getting stuck on the device.

Answer (score 0):

The  default name for application icon is `Icon.png` (not the 1st letter is uppercase - ios filesystem is case-sensitive). However you can specify any other name for application icon in info.plist file - check `Icon File` key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I add the name in my info.plist from my project. Do I put the name of the image with the extention or not ?
Sorry I just start the iOS developpement, one month ago.

Comment: I have the name with extension in my proj